# Enforce uniqueness constraint on text object field

Tags: custom-field, formula-field, page-layout, schema

I am trying to build an Authorization object where the primary key should be an unspecified length alphanumeric string (authorization numbers can originate from different sources hence they can come in multiple formats).

In Schema Builder if I go to `Edit Object Properties`, the `Record Name` can only be `Text` or `Auto Number` type. The latter will always be unique (if one is not messing with the object) but I need the former because a record should be identified or referenced by this unique authorization number. With an `Auto Number`, this would create another layer of indirection, such as referencing files in templates by inode number.

This constraint cannot be imposed on it on the object level (as far as I know) so my next thought was to build this into the layout.

If I create a custom text field, disallow duplicates, and copy the authorization number into both fields (into `Name` that refers to the primary key `Record Name` in the object properties, and into `Authorization Number` text field) then it works, and I have a unique reference for each record in the Authorization object.

My question is, **is there a way to implement this without copying the same data twice**?

Reasons why I need this:

1. It is 2016 and this is implemented in any basic RDBMS for decades. [This has been an ongoing issue for at least 7 years](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqCTAA0&sort=2).
2. Most of the users where I work are blind. (Although this solution would raise questions among sighted users.)

Comment: You can think of creating a Duplicate Management Rule for Authorization Object. Here is the refernce link : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Could you put this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of creating a Duplicate Management Rule for Authorization Object.

**Duplicate Management**
Maintaining clean and accurate data is one of the most important things you can do to help your organization get the most out of Salesforce. With Duplicate Management, you can control whether and when you allow users to create duplicate records inside Salesforce; customize the logic that’s used to identify duplicates; and create reports on the duplicates you do allow users to save.

Important Rules to know in Data Duplicate Management-

**Duplicate Rules**
Duplicate rules are used to control whether and when you can save duplicate records within Salesforce.

**Matching Rules**
Matching rules are used to identify duplicate records within Salesforce.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_prevention_map_of_tasks.htm)